# Update only necessary states in useContext hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

In the following example, a click on the first button re-renders both of the child components (`ComponentOne` and `ComponentTwo`), although the state of the second number does not change (because the whole `useContext` array value changes). I would like to know how we can detect multiple individual values, or any other method to only render states that changed.

```
const TwoNumbers = createContext();

function ComponentOne(){
  const number = useContext(TwoNumbers)[0];

  return(
    <div>{number}</div>
  )
}

function ComponentTwo(){
  const number = useContext(TwoNumbers)[1];

  return(
    <div>{number}</div>
  )
}

function App() {

  const [numberOne, setNumberOne] = useState(0);
  const [numberTwo, setNumberTwo] = useState(0);

  return (
    <TwoNumbers.Provider value={[numberOne, numberTwo]}>
      <div className="App">
        <ComponentOne/>
        <ComponentTwo/>
        <button onClick = {()=>{setNumberOne(numberOne+1)}}>First+1</button>
        <button onClick = {()=>{setNumberTwo(numberTwo+1)}}>Second+1</button>
      </div>
      </TwoNumbers.Provider>
  );
}
```

In real scenario the two numbers will represent the view count and other real-time data I would like to update after the backend updated. I see Stack Overflow is not doing this. Is real-time state matching an expensive move? Does it extensively add more time for page loading?

Comment: ` re-renders both of the two numbers` it's because you are using the entire context in both components, adding `[0]` at the end doesn't make it register only one value magically.

Comment: In the real case the "value" will be a huge json data set. Is there any good practice to re-render what is necessary for the entire page? The page component contains a lot of child components which have their own state variables. Or should I not use `useContext` in this case?

Comment: It's ok to use `useContext`, rerendering a component shouldn't be computation inefficient.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference really

Comment: Thank you I’ll run dev tools to compare different solutions

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create two Contexts and use two context providers. Then each of the child components (`ComponentOne` and `ComponentTwo`) consumes its own respective context. Finally in order to prevent a child component from being updated by its parent (`App`) due to the changes on the context value of the other sibling component, you can use `React.memo`.

```
const ContextNumberOne = createContext();
const ContextNumberTwo = createContext();

React.memo(function ComponentOne(){
  const number = useContext(ContextNumberOne);

  return(
    <div>{number}</div>
  )
})

React.memo(function ComponentTwo(){
  const number = useContext(ContextNumberTwo);

  return(
    <div>{number}</div>
  )
})

function App() {

  const [numberOne, setNumberOne] = useState(0);
  const [numberTwo, setNumberTwo] = useState(0);

  return (
    <ContextNumberOne.Provider value={numberOne}>
       <ContextNumberTwo.Provider value={numberTwo}>
            <div className="App">
                <ComponentOne/>
                <ComponentTwo/>
                <button onClick = {()=>{setNumberOne(numberOne+1)}}>First+1</button>
                <button onClick = {()=>{setNumberTwo(numberTwo+1)}}>Second+1</button>
            </div>
        </ContextNumberTwo.Provider>
     </ContextNumberOne.Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into using Redux instead, it specially solves this problem. You can use [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useSelector) to subscribe to the particular bit of state that you care about, and only rerender when that changes.